# Cannot connect Heroku app to Amazon RDS

Tags: heroku, amazon-rds

I ve deployed an app on Heroku and I m trying to hook up an Amazon RDS add-on. I ve created an Amazon RDS instance and uploaded my Mysql database there.Then I followed all the steps described in the heroku documentation on how to connect to Amazon RDS, including auuthorization process.

https://devcenter.heroku.com//articles/amazon_rds

I have also set the Database URL on the Amazon RDS add-on. I am able to connect to my amazon instance from a mysql management tool ( so the credentials and the host address are correct)

When I run my app I get the following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:138)
    org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
    org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:59)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy19.listPeople(Unknown Source)
    com.example.controller.PersonController.listPeople(PersonController.java:27)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:392)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:206)
    org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76)
    org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:32)
    org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:59)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    $Proxy19.listPeople(Unknown Source)
    com.example.controller.PersonController.listPeople(PersonController.java:27)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Anybody has an idea why this is happening? I have double checked that the credentials and the host address are the correct one

Comment: Can you confirm you added authorization (using your Amazon Console or the commands given in the article) for Heroku to access RDS?

Comment: Yes, as it is suggested on Heroku doc I typed the following :

$ rds-authorize-db-security-group-ingress --db-security-group-name default \ 
    --ec2-security-group-name default \
    --ec2-security-group-owner-id 098166147350 \
    --aws-credential-file ../credential-file-path.template

And it seems it was correct since when I tried to run it again I got the message: " Malformed input-Authorization already
exists: default for owner id 098166147350"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally figured out what was wrong.I initially created an Amazon RDS instance in Ireland  (since I reside in Europe). However Heroku is not able to connect to Ireland instances (since apparently they reside in US and they are using EC instances in US). So I created another instance in US East(N. Virginia) and worked!!! I m not sure if it works also with the other Amazon sites at US West (Oregon,N.California).